# Is it OK to use the MinGW version of git with Cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin, mingw

I use cygwin as main shell when programming on Windows rather than git bash as I want to have access to additional programs that available on Cygwin so I installed the git package for Cygwin so that I can use git there and avoid the need to switch shells.

Recently I needed to start using git lfs but its not available for Cygwin (at least as far as I aware). I tried running the MinGW version of git (located in c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin) that comes with git for Windows from Cygwin. I was expecting it to not recognize the Cygwin absolute file paths as on Cygwin paths look like /cygdrive/c/foo/bar instead of /c/foo/bar as they are on MinGW, but to my surprise it seems to work fine.

So am thinking I can just uninstall the cygwin git and put the MinGW version on my Cygwin path.

The potential upside of working like this is that I will always have access to an up to date version of git and its  extensions rather than relying on whats available for cygwin.

Is there any downside to running git like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the downsides are minor, and have done this myself. But you do have all the standard things that come up when mixing Windows with a Unix-like environment, such as:

- File modes. The MinGW git may think a file is executable when the Cygwin git may not, and the repository may end up with some files marked as non-executable when they should be executable, or vice-versa. I've seen situations where, after a checkout, git thinks the file mode has changed, even though it hasn't. Look at the `core.filemode` configuration setting when trying to deal with this issue. You may need to set it to `false` if you run into problems.
- Filename casing. Possibly you end up with an incorrect casing the your repository, which might or might not affect one version of git differently than the other. I never ran into this problem myself, but it sure seems like it could be a possible problem. There is a `core.ignorecase` configuration setting related to this, but normally git sets it correctly for the OS and filesystem so normally you should not change it. (On Windows, it would normally be `true`, I think even with Cygwin.)
- Line endings. Generally, git tries to do the right thing. But if you run into problems look at the `core.autocrlf` configuration setting.

Comment: I use cygwin git, mingw git and git for windows interchangeably with no problems. As mentioned above, you want to ignore file mode, I have never found filename casing to be a problem, set line endings to input. Repositories that have name collisions when you ignore case are usually encouraged to fix that problem very fast. Use a file editor that preserves line endings, and can change line endings. Keep the git versions the same or very close!

Comment: I found that replacing posix=0 with noacl in /etc/fstab to turn of posix file permission emulation seems to solve issues with file modes.